# Is it possible to load javascript code on your HTML file on GitHub pages?

Tags: javascript

This is my GitHub pages site at https://awsomeguy563.github.io/

The sit runs on this repo: https://github.com/awsomeguy563/awsomeguy563.github.io

And I have a local repository on my laptop that is a clone of this remote repository.

I want to be able to display my javascript code on the website, but nothing works. Can someone recommend me the easiest way to do this? The javascript code is on the repository. And I have a local repository on my laptop.

The javascript code is code.js on the repository above.

Comment: But your script loads there normally what it does is that it produces error becuase you can't run `script` working with `DOM` in the `head`

Comment: Did it fix that problem?

Comment: Yup it did! ,Thanks so much,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `code.js` is there and it's loaded. What you are doing wrong is that you are loading that `script` in `head` tag so it executes before the body is loaded and that produces that error.

To solve it you can move the `script` under closing `body` tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Life</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#14FFB0">
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="600" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>
<script src="code.js"></script>
</html>
```

**Or you can keep the `script` tag where is it and** you can load the function `onLoad`

```
function runOnLoad() {
   var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
   var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
   ctx.clearRect(0,0,800,600);
   ctx.fillStyle = "red";
   ctx.fillRect(10,10,100,100);
}
```

And in html just update body tag

```
<body bgcolor="#14FFB0" onload="runOnLoad()">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the raw js file path in your HTML:

```
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/awsomeguy563/awsomeguy563.github.io/master/code.js"></script>
```